# Is it considered an antipattern to nest Promise chains?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I was using Firebase and I wrote a code like this:

```js
firebase.database().ref().child('someChild').set({
    someKey: 'someValue'
}).then(() => {
    return firebase.database().ref().child('someChild').once('value')
        .then(snapshot => snapshot.val().someKey);
}).then(insertedData => {
    console.log('Your inserted data:' + insertedData);
});
```

As you can see, I have another Promise inside my outer Promise (nesting). Is this considered an antipattern and should I avoid it?

Comment: No, that's actually a good thing. Because like this your outer promise will wait for your inner promise to complete. Only if you wouldn't return your inner promise it would be bad, because you couldn't be certain that your full chain ran through. If you want to avoid it nowadays, I guess going with `async/await` might be an option, but its still just some syntax sugar coding for promises in the end

Comment: @Icepickle I see, I thought that I was doing something rather odd as I have not seen examples like those in the docs I read. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: everything would be much easier and understandable with async/await though

Comment: Well, to be fair, I haven't look at the code, I was only interested in answering the question about nesting promises ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting promises is not the anti pattern here, it's actually advised to do so. The anti-pattern part would be to set async await execution block. Since await waits the call to be ended and blocks the thread but executes the other child threads. The code alone is not enough to determine if it's an anti-pattern but chain nesting is commonly used since there are processes that needs to be done before the other "then"-s executes.